# How to search the location of Shell Script

Tags: cron, scripts

```
# 59 23 * * 1 sh /rsync01.sh
# 59 23 * * 2 sh /rsync02.sh
# 59 23 * * 3 sh /rsync03.sh
# 59 23 * * 4 sh /rsync04.sh
# 59 23 * * 5 sh /rsync05.sh
# 59 23 * * 6 sh /rsync06.sh
# 59 23 * * 0 sh /rsync07.sh 
* * * * 6 sh /z_Saturday.sh
* * * * 6 sh /z_Saturday1.sh
* * * * 6 sh /z_Saturday2.sh
* * * * 1-5 sh /up_to_0200h.sh
* * * * 1-5 sh /up_to_0300h.sh
* * * * 1-5 sh /up_to_0400h.sh
* * * * 1-5 sh /up_to_0500h.sh
* * * * 1-5 sh /up_to_0600h.sh
* * * * 1-5 sh /up_to_0630h.sh
* * * * 1-5 sh /up_to_0700h.sh
* * * * 1-5 sh /up_to_0730h.sh
* * * * 1-5 sh /after_0730h.sh**
```

My boss wants that i copy the shell script and paste the data in a new script. but I don't know how to search this file and how to edit it please guide me.

Comment: `cd /` and `ls` command will list your files.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options to locate a file:

1. using `find`: `find / -name 'the_name_of_the_file'` (You are allowed to use * as well.)
2. using `locate`: first build the database with: `sudo updatedb`, after that you can use `locate the_name_of_the_file`
3. using `whereis`: `whereis the_name_of_my_script` (Note that the script must be in $PATH.)
4. using `which`: `which the_name_of_my_script` (Here also it must be in $PATH)

Answer (score 2):

- Those scripts are in the ROOT directory. 1st time I see this done like this and it feels ... wrong. Plese put them in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. You can use `cd /` and `ls -l` to show you a list of those files. Editing is done with `vi` or another command line editor.
- **This** file you posted is the crontab file and is edited with `crontab -e` but you need to be logged in as the user this crontab belongs to. If that is `root` you need root access to be able to edit this.
- The lines with a # in front are commented and not executed.